# Linking works, but ldd does not show linked libraries and runtime fails

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, ldd

I'm trying to compile a library from [this](https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl) repo. Running `make test` in the root folder produces an executable file `tests` that depends on `libpcreposix` and `libpcre`. The linking line looks like this:

```
gfortran -std=f2008 -fall-intrinsics -ffree-line-length-none -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-target-lifetime -Wno-compare-reals -Jbuild.gnu.debug -g -Og -fcheck=bounds,do,mem,pointer,recursion -Isrc -Itests  -DUSE_PCRE tests/tests.F90 build.gnu.debug/*.o -lpcreposix -lpcre -o build.gnu.debug/tests
```

As you can see, the required libraries are linked via `-lpcreposix -lpcre` and this line executes successfully, producing executable `tests`, which, however, crashes at runtime. I strongly suspect that this crash has something to do with these libraries, so I ran `ldd tests`, which showed the following output:

```
$ ldd build.gnu.debug/tests
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe5b481000)
libgfortran.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007fd307a59000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd30790a000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd3078ef000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fd3078a5000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd3076b3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd307e24000)
```

As you can see, `libpcreposix` and `libpcre` and not even on this list. The libraries were installed via `sudo apt install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` and I can see them in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcreposix.so.3.13` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3`. I have added this path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which did not even exist before that), but it did not change anything.

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The executable `tests` definitely depends on these libraries, but just in case I have also tried to add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the linking line, which also did not change anything. I have tried the exact same sequence of actions on another machine and it worked without issues (and I was able to see the required libraries in the output of `ldd`), so it has to be related with the setup of my machine. The machine where I have issues is a recently created virtual machine (Ubuntu 20), so I might have forgotten to install of set up something here.

Edit:

Output of linking with `-Wl,--verbose`:

```
$ gfortran -std=f2008 -fall-intrinsics -ffree-line-length-none -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-target-lifetime -Wno-compare-reals -Jbuild.gnu.debug -g -Og -fcheck=bounds,do,mem,pointer,recursion -Isrc -Itests  -DUSE_PCRE tests/tests.F90 build.gnu.debug/*.o -lpcreposix -lpcre -o build.gnu.debug/tests -Wl,--verbose
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -pie -z combreloc -z separate-code -z relro -z now */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
          "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id  : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      *(.rela.iplt)
    }
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.sec        : { *(.plt.sec) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(SORT(.text.sorted.*))
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  /* Adjust the address for the rodata segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = SEGMENT_START("rodata-segment", ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)));
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr   : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata      :
   {
     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__tdata_start = .);
     *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*)
   }
  .tbss       : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got.plt) *(.igot.plt) *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (0, .);
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we do not
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  .gnu.build.attributes : { *(.gnu.build.attributes .gnu.build.attributes.*) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3 */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF Extension.  */
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccJNio1k.o succeeded
/tmp/ccJNio1k.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/Animals.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/Animals.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlAlgorithmsTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlAlgorithmsTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlArrayIntAlgorithms.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlArrayIntAlgorithms.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlArrayTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlArrayTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayIntAlgorithms.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayIntAlgorithms.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayInt.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayInt.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayLeaky.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayLeaky.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayMovableLeaky.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayMovableLeaky.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayPoint2DAlgorithms.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayPoint2DAlgorithms.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayPoint2D.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayPoint2D.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayString.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayString.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlDynArrayTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHashMapStringInt.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHashMapStringInt.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHashMapStrInt.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHashMapStrInt.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHashMapTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHashMapTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHash.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHash.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHashSetInt.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHashSetInt.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHashSetString.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHashSetString.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlHashSetTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlHashSetTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlKinds.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlKinds.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlListIntAlgorithms.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlListIntAlgorithms.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlListInt.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlListInt.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlListLeaky.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlListLeaky.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlListMovableLeaky.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlListMovableLeaky.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlListTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlListTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlRegex.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlRegex.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlRegexTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlRegexTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlSharedPtrInt.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlSharedPtrInt.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlSharedPtrTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlSharedPtrTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlStringAlgorithms.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlStringAlgorithms.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlString.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlString.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlStringTests.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlStringTests.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/ftlTestTools.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/ftlTestTools.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/Leaky.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/Leaky.o
attempt to open build.gnu.debug/Point2D.o succeeded
build.gnu.debug/Point2D.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libpcreposix.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libpcreposix.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcreposix.so succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcreposix.so
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libpcre.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libpcre.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgfortran.so succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgfortran.so
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libquadmath.so succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libquadmath.so
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libm.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgcc.a
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o
attempt to open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o succeeded
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
libquadmath.so.0 needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgfortran.so
found libquadmath.so at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libquadmath.so
libgcc_s.so.1 needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgfortran.so
found libgcc_s.so.1 at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libgfortran.so
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: Try running the linker in a verbose mode. It may have picked static libraries from a place you don't intend to use.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I've looked through the verbose output, but did not find any pertinent information there, although I wasn't entirely sure what to look at exactly. However, the same folder (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu) also has static versions of these libraries (.a). I've tried renaming both static and shared versions. Linker could not find them anymore, so that folder is the only location. Then I tried renaming back only the shared libraries. The linker worked, but ldd still does not show them.

Comment: `ldd` doesn't show any static libraries. It has no idea what a static library is. Names of static libraries do not show up in the executable. It looks like the linker picked static versions of these libraries.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. but I have renamed the static ones. I expect that only dynamic versions should be available to the linker.

Comment: You should post your verbose output

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have updated the question.

Comment: This doesn't run the linker in verbose mode, try `-Wl,--verbose`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Sorry, I have updated the question again.

Comment: If the linker opens a shared library but does not add it to the NEEDED list, it could mean that the library isn't really needed. Otherwise I have no idea what the reason of this could be. Try building without these libraries and see what happens.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. But I have also tried linking it with -Wl,--no-as-needed and it still does not show up. It is possible to compile that executable without linking the libraries, but then it picks up another library by default, so it technically works, but not as I want.

Comment: "I have also tried linking it with -Wl,--no-as-needed and it still does not show up" I have never seen anything like that, it should never happen, I think there is a bug somewhere in your procedure. "It is possible to compile that executable without linking the libraries" Then they are not needed. "but then it picks up another library by default" I don't understand this sentence. How does it pick up a library it is not linked with? Does it do dlopen?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I'm not completely sure, that is what is written on the wiki page of that project https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl/wiki/ftlRegex (2nd options under building & linking)

Comment: -Wl,--no-as-needed should include the shared library to DL_NEEDED, period. If it doesn't then either you don't have a shared lib (but the logs say otherwise) or you are not looking at the right executable.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Well, the linking line unambiguously specifies the name of the generated executable via `-o build.gnu.debug/tests`, so I'm fairly confident I'm looking at the right executable.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. This is what I think happens here. `libpcreposix` provides posix-compatible api to `pcre`, so basically functions with the same signatures as in standard `<regex.h>`. An implementation of these functions should be provided by one of the standard libraries linked to this executable by default. After the standard library is linked, the dependencies are satisfied. Maybe linker is ignoring libpcreposix because it exports the same interface? Is there a way I could check any of these assumptions or instruct linker to use libpcreposix as implementation instead of the standard library?

Comment: -Wl,--no-as-needed causes the library to be recorded in DL_NEEDED, regardless. It doesn't mater what provides what and who calls whom.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Ok, I just learned that -Wl,--no-as-needed only affects the libraries specified after this option. I was putting it at the end of the linking command and thought that it affects the whole command. After I changed its position, the libraries started showing up. Unfortunately, that did not fix the runtime issue, but that is another question now.